# jQuery - Ajax Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two input elements in my page.

```
<input type="button" id="
MyButton" onclick="SomeFunction()" value="click me" />
    <input type="text" id="text" />
```

I'm trying to get "Hello World" text from my `a1.ph`p using jQuery ajax, but I'm getting error, which says :

> Network Error: Failed to execute 'send' on XMLHttpRequest: Failed to load 'file:///C:/a1.php'

Here's my javaScript function:

```
function SomeFunction()
    {
        //alert("AAAAAAAAAA");
        jQuery("#text").val("AAA"); 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "a1.php",
            success: function() {
                alert("OK");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

}
```

Please help me to fix this little problem.

Comment: You can see from the error that the file failed to load. Are you sure that is the correct file location for `a1.php`?

Comment: Are you opening this file directry into browser, instead of accesing it via eg. `http://localhost/`?

Comment: yes i'm opening it directly without accessing localhost

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you path location isn't right, you can do something like:

```
...
url: '/a1.php' OR url: 'http://localhost/myproject/a1.php'
...
```

Comment: Are you using virtual host with Apache ou you access your URL directly? Can you put the "full" url here? Thanks...

Comment: No, i'm not using apache,it's just a html file which i moved into a folder on my desktop

Comment: the full url is C:\Users\My\Desktop\jQuery-Ajax\a1.php

Comment: Do you sure you setup you environment first ?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by saying "Environment"

Comment: Try it: [Installing your environment](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html) - then you can run PHP pages and make the test again

Answer (score -4):

Your a1.php file must be directly inside your C: drive with this code. If it isn't you'll get this error.

Comment: Visiting file this way, even if it is on drive, wont execute it as of it shoud with PHP script.